# Add URL to classpath via command line

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent to this:

```
java.exe -cp "C:\my_test\my_jar.jar;C:\my_test\lib\*;" com.test.Main
```

but using an URL like this:

```
 java.exe -cp "http:\\192.168.1.12\my_test\my_jar.jar;http:\\192.168.1.12\my_test\lib\*;" com.test.Main
```

The error is: `Could not find or load main class`, but if I look into `http:\\192.168.1.12\my_test\my_jar.jar` I can see my Main class there. Is there any way I can do this **via command line**?

P.S: I can reach `http:\\192.168.1.12\my_test\my_jar.jar` via browser

Comment: The slashes are the other way. It's `http://`, not http:\\.

Comment: Already tried that but it keeps saying `Could not find or load main class`. But if I try to access `http:\\192.168.1.12\my_test\my_jar.jar` I can see my Main class there

Comment: The classpath is composed of jar files and directories. Not of http URLs. You'll have to programmatically create a UrlClassLoader to load classes from a server that way.

Comment: Make it an answer so I can mark as correct @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath is composed of jar files and directories. Not of http URLs. You'll have to programmatically create a UrlClassLoader to load classes from a server that way.